# How to interchange rows and columns in panda dataframe

Tags: pandas

i m reading a csv file using pandas library. I want to interchange rows and columns but main issue is  in Status column ..there is repetition of values after every three rows in this column....so transpose is making all the row values to columns...but in place  i just want only three column...i.e. Confirmed, Recovered, Deceased for every date.. please find the attachment where i have shown sample input as well as sample output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s24qp.png)

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: pls provide your data as text not images

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of using `stack()` and `unstack()`

```
import random
s = 10
d = pd.date_range("01-Jan-2021", periods=s)
cols = ["TT","AN","AP"]
df = pd.DataFrame([{**{"Date":dd, "Status":st}, **{c:random.randint(1,50) for c in cols}}  
              for dd in d 
              for st in ["Confirmed","Recovered","Deceased"]])

df.set_index(["Date","Status"]).rename_axis(columns="State").stack().unstack(1)
```

#### before

```
         Date     Status  TT  AN  AP
0  2021-01-01  Confirmed   5  44  17
1  2021-01-01  Recovered  44   5  48
2  2021-01-01   Deceased  27   3  24
3  2021-01-02  Confirmed  33  14  38
4  2021-01-02  Recovered  21  15   6
5  2021-01-02   Deceased  15  37   8
6  2021-01-03  Confirmed  15  20  36
7  2021-01-03  Recovered  18  19  44
8  2021-01-03   Deceased  37  22   1
9  2021-01-04  Confirmed  16  35  37
10 2021-01-04  Recovered  30  45  49
11 2021-01-04   Deceased  35   7  18
```

#### after

```
Status            Confirmed  Deceased  Recovered
Date       State                                
2021-01-01 TT             5        27         44
           AN            44         3          5
           AP            17        24         48
2021-01-02 TT            33        15         21
           AN            14        37         15
           AP            38         8          6
2021-01-03 TT            15        37         18
           AN            20        22         19
           AP            36         1         44
2021-01-04 TT            16        35         30
           AN            35         7         45
           AP            37        18         49
```